# Проблема с выводом c++

Tags: c++, сортировка

Есть структура Студент:

```
struct Stud
{
    string firstName;
    string secondName;
    int averageScore;
};
```

Есть класс Группа:

```
class Group
{
private:
    string nameGroup;
    vector<Stud> students;
public:
...
}
```

Сортировка в main:

```
vector<Group> groups;
sort(groups.begin(), groups.end());
copy(groups.begin(), groups.end(), ostream_iterator<Group>(cout));
```

Перегрузил оператор вывода:

```
const string& Group::getNameGroup()const
{
    return nameGroup;
}
void Group::outputStudents(ostream& out)const
{
    copy(students.begin(), students.end(), ostream_iterator<Stud>(out, " "));
}
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Group& group)
{
    out << group.getNameGroup();
    group.outputStudents(out);
    return out;
}
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Stud& stud)
{
    out << "\t" << stud.firstName
        << "\t" << stud.secondName
        << "\t" << stud.averageScore<<"\n";
    return out;
}
```

После выполнения `sort` выводит только название группы и ссылается на

```
void Group::outputStudents(ostream& out)const
    {
        copy(students.begin(), students.end(), ostream_iterator<Stud>(out, " "));
    }
```

Пишет, что vector iterators incompatible.
Извините за беспокойствие, может тут все и очевидно, но я новичек в С++ и пока не могу понять в чём тут ошибка.

Comment: И да, до сортировки Сopy нормально работало, но после нет.

Comment: Весь код целиком бы привели, или лучше оформить пример на [coliru.stacked-crooked.com](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com) так проще будет вам помочь, да и нагляднее..

Comment: Не приведен оператор сравнения, использующийся для сортировки (он у вас где-то есть, ибо без него бы даже не скомпилировалось). А так, в том, что пока приведено, проблем не видно. Проблема в чем-то другом.

Comment: определите  bool Group::operator<(const Group&)